# Write common class for Browser and node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've written a wrapper around promises to handle multiple promises and render them beautifully on the browser window. Which I achieved be creating 3 classes `Process`, `ProcessQueue` and `ProcessStatus`

Now I want to decouple the DOM manipulation from that code, and also port the Promise handling module to node.js too.

I saw a this example on [geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-share-code-between-node-js-and-the-browser/). But I'm not sure how do I achieve that for classes.

I've removed the DOM manipulation code and added the import statements.

**Process.js**

```
import { ProcessStatus } from './ProcessStatus';

class Process {
    constructor(invoker) {
        if (invoker instanceof Function) {
            this._promise = new Promise(invoker);
        } else if (invoker instanceof Promise) {
            this._promise = invoker;
        } else {
            throw new TypeError('Invalid invoker passed for Process constructor');
        }

        this._status = ProcessStatus.INPROGRESS;
        this._promise.then(function () {
            this._status = ProcessStatus.SUCCESS;
        }.bind(this), function () {
            this._status = ProcessStatus.FAILED;
        }.bind(this));

    }

    then(resolve, reject) {
        return this._promise.then(resolve, reject);
    }

    catch(reject) {
        return this._promise.catch(reject);
    }

    getStatus() {
        return this._status;
    }
}
export default Process;
```

**ProcessQueue.js**

```
import { ProcessStatus } from './ProcessStatus';
import { Process } from './Process';

class ProcessQueue {
    constructor() {

        this._status = ProcessStatus.INPROGRESS;
        this._promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            this._resolve = resolve;
            this._reject = reject;
        }.bind(this));

        this._processList = [];
        this._resolvedCount = 0;
        this._successCount = 0;
        this._failureCount = 0;

        this._successCallback = function() {
            this._resolvedCount++;
            this._successCount++;
            if (this._resolvedCount == this._processList.length) {
                if (this._failureCount == 0) {
                    this._status = ProcessStatus.SUCCESS;
                    this._resolve();
                } else {
                    this._status = ProcessStatus.FAILED;
                    this._reject();
                }
            }
        }

        this._failureCallback = function() {
            this._resolvedCount++;
            this._failureCount++;
            if (this._resolvedCount == this._processList.length) {
                this._status = ProcessStatus.FAILED;
                this._reject();
            }
        }
    }

    push(process) {
        if (process instanceof Process || process instanceof ProcessQueue) {
            process.then(this._successCallback, this._failureCallback);
        } else {
            throw new TypeError('Invalid process type pushed to the queue');
        }
        this._processList.push(process);
    }

    then(resolve, reject) {
        return this._promise.then(resolve, reject);
    }

    catch(reject) {
        return this._promise.catch(reject);
    }

    getStatus() {
        return this._status;
    }
}
export default ProcessQueue;
```

**ProcessStatus**

```
ProcessStatus = Object.freeze({
    'INPROGRESS': 'INPROGRESS',
    'SUCCESS': 'SUCCESS',
    'FAILED': 'FAILED'
});
export default ProcessStatus;
```

Code reference: https://github.com/encryptorcode/process-manager/tree/master/src

Comment: Ok, so what you'll want to do is to decouple the DOM manipulation from that code and then port the Promise handling module to node.js

Comment: Yes, @JaromandaX you got me right.